Why is this macro redefined, only if cross compiling, and even if there is #ifndef?
I'm trying to cross compile the Azure IoT C SDK. The compilation goes fine for native builds, but when cross compiling I get
[ 33%] Building C object out/uamqp/CMakeFiles/uamqp.dir/src/header_detect_io.c.o
In file included from /home/abertulli/two_lidars/azure-iot-sdk-c/uamqp/inc/azure_uamqp_c/server_protocol_io.h:11:0,
                 from /home/abertulli/two_lidars/azure-iot-sdk-c/uamqp/src/header_detect_io.c:13:
/opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/stdint.h:266:0: error: "SIZE_MAX" redefined [-Werror]
 #   define SIZE_MAX  (4294967295U)

In file included from /home/abertulli/two_lidars/azure-iot-sdk-c/uamqp/src/header_detect_io.c:11:0:
/home/abertulli/two_lidars/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/safe_math.h:8:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)((size_t)~(size_t)0))

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [out/uamqp/CMakeFiles/uamqp.dir/build.make:202: out/uamqp/CMakeFiles/uamqp.dir/src/header_detect_io.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:594: out/uamqp/CMakeFiles/uamqp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

But I see in /opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/stdint.h (in the sysroot of the compiler)
/* Limit of `size_t' type.  */
# if __WORDSIZE == 64
#  define SIZE_MAX      (18446744073709551615UL)
# else
#  ifdef __WORDSIZE32_SIZE_ULONG
#   define SIZE_MAX     (4294967295UL)
#  else
#   define SIZE_MAX     (4294967295U)      // <-------- HERE
#  endif
# endif

and in ~/two_lidars/azure-iot-sdk-c/c-utility/inc/azure_c_shared_utility/safe_math.h
#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)((size_t)~(size_t)0))     // <---------- HERE
#endif

Why does it get redefined, even if there is #ifndef? My guess is that the second file gets compiled first, but why this behaviour shows up only when cross-compiling? And to fix this, should I place a #ifndef in the sysroot include?

The error message looks like the problem is the first box doesn't have an #ifndef and the second box was the definition. note: this is the location of the previous definition
#define SIZE_MAX ((size_t)((size_t)~(size_t)0))

It is probably missing an explicit #include <stdint.h> somewhere and it is getting included accidentally for the native build.

Only one of the header files checks to see if SIZE_MAX is already defined, so if that header file is included first, then the other header file will attempt to redefine it.

“And to fix this, should I place a #ifndef in the sysroot include?” No, but you can try manually including stdint.h first. The include guards in the headers should then guarantee the expected result.

I wonder why they included that snippet in "safe_math.h" in the first place? I know MSVC historically did not have <stdint.h>.

Indeed, @IanAbbott.  And they having made that choice, I wonder why they chose that abomination of a definition, with the extra casts.  But Microsoft has never been that good at implementing C, so I guess it's not surprising that they're also mediocre at using it.

@JohnBollinger Yes, they managed to define it in such a way that it cannot be used in preprocessor constant expressions.

The git commit messages associated with the addition of, and changes to, safe_math.h are pretty vacant too.

why this behaviour shows up only when cross-compiling? When does the behavior not show up? You are crosscompiling for? Using what compiler and compiler options and which toolchain and which C standard library?

Thanks to everyone for the comments, you helped identifying the problem. It was apparently a problem of misordered/misplaced #includes in the Azure SDK code. Guarding the #define in the stdint.h solved the issue, tho of course it is a temporary workaround, not to be used in production code! In the end, I opened an issue on the Azure repo, where the mantainers kindly and quickly fixed the problem.
EDIT this is the issue, if you are interested in the fix while it's waiting to getting merged

It would be better if you can link to the issue in this answer.
